# Zoom the page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, zooming

How to zoom in/out a page using JavaScript ?

= please but comments to explain the code =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function ajustaZoom() {
        document.body.style.zoom = "67%" 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function ZoomIn()
{
    var Page = document.getElementById('Body');
    var zoom = parseInt(Page.style.zoom) + 50 +'%'
    Page.style.zoom = zoom;
    return false;
}

function ZoomOut()
{
    var Page = document.getElementById('Body');
    var zoom = parseInt(Page.style.zoom) - 50 +'%'
    Page.style.zoom = zoom;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try this by putting the required percentage you want to zoom in or out